# How to get buffer from remote audio file?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

Currently i made it working with local audio file, but my goal is to make it working with remote audio files.

**Here is my part of code for local audio file**

```
let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileUrl)
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
```

i've tried to use it with remote url, but got exception in openning remote file

```
Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=2003334207 "(null)" UserInfo={failed call=ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)}
```

is there a way to open remote file and get buffer of this file? ( without downloading it first).

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an error that you get.

Comment: @inokey updated

Comment: Have you tried using `init(forReading:commonFormat:interleaved:)`  on AudioFile? Also it looks like error is related to URL itself. Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: Also I couldn't find information on possibility to init AVAudioFile with remote url. it seems like it's only possible to do from disk or ram.